# insert multiple rows using join in a table

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I want to insert multiple rows in a table from different tables using join by a single query.When I run the below query it shows error

```
$insert=DB::table('tableA')->insert(DB::raw('SELECT ss.col1,ts.col2,ts.col3,ts.col4,ts.col5,
                5 AS col6 FROM 
                tableB AS ts
                 INNER JOIN tableC AS t ON ts.col2=t.id 
                 INNER JOIN tableD AS ss 
                 ON ts.col1=ss.col1 
                 AND ts.col3=ss.col3
                 AND ts.col4=ss.col4 
                 AND ts.col5=ss.col5
                 INNER JOIN tableE AS s 
                 ON ss.col1=s.id
                 WHERE t.status=1
                 AND s.status=1'));
```

> Error:Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert()
>   must be of the type array, object given.

actually it return object where as insert method expects array. I used raw query it inserts the data but timestamp doesn't populate and it doesn't return the inserted rows count as well.

how can I get both using laravel query builder ??

Comment: the issue I think is you are trying to insert values generated from a join and hence the issue..you need to ensure that the columns you trying to add should match the columns defined in the table

Comment: @DhavalChheda it matches the columns.insert method expects array but the value generated from join return array object .

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work if columns in `tableA` have the same names as in your select:

```
$insert=DB::table('tableA')
->insert(json_decode(json_encode(DB::select('SELECT ss.col1,ts.col2,ts.col3,ts.col4,ts.col5,
                5 AS col6 FROM 
                tableB AS ts
                 INNER JOIN tableC AS t ON ts.col2=t.id 
                 INNER JOIN tableD AS ss 
                 ON ts.col1=ss.col1 
                 AND ts.col3=ss.col3
                 AND ts.col4=ss.col4 
                 AND ts.col5=ss.col5
                 INNER JOIN tableE AS s 
                 ON ss.col1=s.id
                 WHERE t.status=1
                 AND s.status=1')),true));
```

Comment: created_at and updated_at column doesn't populate.actually I need both inserted rows count and timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

First you can store the result of the first query in a variable:

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT ss.col1,ts.col2,ts.col3,ts.col4,ts.col5,
    5 AS col6 FROM 
    tableB AS ts
    INNER JOIN tableC AS t ON ts.col2=t.id 
    INNER JOIN tableD AS ss 
    ON ts.col1=ss.col1 
    AND ts.col3=ss.col3
    AND ts.col4=ss.col4 
    AND ts.col5=ss.col5
    INNER JOIN tableE AS s 
    ON ss.col1=s.id
    WHERE t.status=1
    AND s.status=1');
```

Then convert the data to array:

```
$data = collect($data)->map(function($x){ return (array) $x; })->toArray();
```

And finally insert it into DB, supposing the columns match.

```
$insert = DB::table('tableA')->insert($data);
```

## EDIT

You can use this code to push the values for `timestamps` fields, supposing this two fields are ate the end of the table's specification, ensuring the columns match with values:

```
$data = collect($data)->map(function($x){ 
    return array_push((array) $x, date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
})->toArray();
```

Comment: @Jimenez created_at and updated_at column doesn't populate.